# Help MMO Tcp Packet

Tags: protocol, game-hacking, networking, game

I'm trying re-send the packets that an MMO sends to the server just to learn more about packets. The game uses TCP.

I sent the same message in the game chat "oi"
to analyze the packages sent to the server and these are some examples:

```
\x80\x00=\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01c\x02\x01\x00\x01a\x03\x00\r\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01c\x08\x00\x03msg\x00\x01r\x04\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x02\x00\x03msg\x08\x00\x02oi\x00\x01.\x04\xe4\x08a>

\x80\x00=\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01c\x02\x01\x00\x01a\x03\x00\r\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01c\x08\x00\x03msg\x00\x01r\x04\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x02\x00\x03msg\x08\x00\x02oi\x00\x01.\x04\x96-\xad\xf5

\x80\x00=\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01c\x02\x01\x00\x01a\x03\x00\r\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01c\x08\x00\x03msg\x00\x01r\x04\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x02\x00\x03msg\x08\x00\x02oi\x00\x01.\x04\x98\x01U\x80

\x80\x00=\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01c\x02\x01\x00\x01a\x03\x00\r\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01c\x08\x00\x03msg\x00\x01r\x04\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x02\x00\x03msg\x08\x00\x02oi\x00\x01.\x04\r\xc9D\x1f
```

As you can see, the end of each packet is changed with each packet sent to the server. Does anyone have any idea what these values ​​at the end of each packet might mean? I want to be able to send my own packets

Comment: Could be some sort of packet counter. But the used encoding makes it pretty hard do read the actual values. A common encoding like hexadecimal or a hex-dump.

Comment: @Robert what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: @Rck_ - Dump the contents of these messages again, but use entirely hexadecimal notation. If possible, separate the hex into 32-bit values. Some of the contents of your message is presented here as ASCII and some as hex, making it impossible to draw any conclusions.